# If object is pushed back and forth did Work occur?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

Please help! Trying to resolve family disagreement over basic physics.

If an object is moved in one direction with a force applied in that direction of movement.  Then same object is moved in the opposite direction (with force in direction of movement) and the object is returned back to the origin at very beginning. One member of family believes that because no net movement occurred between start and end of entire problem, that therefore no movement occurred and therefore no Work occurred. Another member of family believes that work occurs moving the object in both directions and the work is additive since the work is positive in both independent instances of movement.   Which is correct?

Comment: Are there other forces involved? Did the object start at rest? Did it end at rest?

Comment: Started at rest and ended at rest, yes.  Just very basic stuff.  Thanks for help even though this is probably super simple.

Comment: @Wild that is not possible. Both your description in the question and your clarification are impossible. If the force is always in the direction of motion then there is no turning and no deceleration or stopping. It can only accelerate in the direction of motion. Because of this inconsistency your answers will probably be problematic. ex falso quodlibet

Comment: is there friction? is the object skidding as it moves?

Answer (score 3):

If the object starts and ends at rest, then its change in kinetic energy is zero, and so the work-energy theorem
\begin{align}
W_{\text{net}} = \Delta K
\end{align}
tells us that no net work was done on object. However, as @march points out in their comment, we can't make this conclusion based only on the fact that the net displacement is zero. If the net force were *constant*, then we could say $W_{\text{net}} = \vec{F}_{\text{net}} \cdot \Delta \vec{r}$, and this would be zero if $\Delta r$ were zero, but that's not the case here. It's only an accident that this argument gets to the correct solution.

The other position (net work was done) also relies on a faulty argument, and it gets the answer wrong, but why? After all, we push the object right and it moves to the right, then we push the object left and it moves to the left. If we pushed in the same direction as the displacement in each step, how did we avoid doing work?

The answer is that we *did not* actually push in the same direction the whole time. We start pushing the object right, and indeed we do positive work on it in doing so. But in order for the object to turn around and start moving left, we must do negative work on it to bring it to rest. In other words, we must have exerted a force opposite the direction of motion at least momentarily. At the turning point, when the object is at rest, the net work we have done is zero. The same thing holds going back. Initially we do positive work as we displace the object in the direction of the force we apply, but to bring the object to rest at the end, we must do negative work, and we end up with a balance of zero net work done.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that *both* family members are wrong: the one that thinks that the work is zero thinks it's because the net displacement is zero, but net positive work can be done while still having a net displacement of zero.

Answer (score 1):

See in reality dissipative forces exist. And hence when we move an object from one place to other the dissipative forces acts and dissipates some energy. When we move it back to the original position, then it dissipates some more energy. This leads to a net non-zero dissipation of energy.

Had there been no dissipative forces then there wouldn't be any loss of energy and hence the first argument would be correct. But since they do exist therefore the second argument must be correct.

If there still remains any speck of doubt then consider the following:

### A physical situation:

You have been hired to move a boulder. But the task involves moving it to a place 5 meter away from the original position, and then returning it back to the original position. Your wage is proportional to the energy you spend during the entire process i.e., the amount of work that you do. The employer asks your input on the amount of work that you did. The wage is as follows:

- If work>0 then employer pays you certanin amount, say, $\$x$.
- If work=0 then then employer does not pay you.
- If work <0 then you pay the employer that certain amount $\$x$.

So what would be your answer? Would it be zero or non-zero? If non-zero would it be positive or negative?